# Formatação para alterar Cor e Status dependendo da Condicional de outra célula

Tags: microsoft-excel, condição

```
VALOR= A/B      0   1   PERIGOSO
                2   3   POBRE
IA= A (400)/    3   4   QUESTIONÁVEL
    70          5   6   CONFIÁVEL
    5,71        7   8   BOM
                >   9   EXCELENTE
```

Quero automatizar uma planilha para obter o resultado da divisão que selecionaria automaticamente a célula "BOM", sendo o valor entre 5 a 6 por exemplo, na condição SE não consigo obter o resultado. Como resolver este problema?

Agradeço pela ajuda.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual tecnologia você quer utilizar para resolver o problema? VBA, VS Tools for Office, OOXML, Sharepoint...?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar formatação condicional para formatar as cores destas duas células baseado em valores.

### Formatação Condicional

#### Abrir a formatação condicional

Selecione as duas células que serão preenchidas com cor, a com o valor e o resultado (Bom,excelente, etc.)

Abra a `Formatação Condicional` > `Nova Regra` > `Usar uma fórmula para determinar quais células devem ser formatadas`

#### Formatar por fórmula

No campo `Formatar valores em que esta fórmula é verdadeira` inserir o intervalo de valores em que a fórmula vai preencher a cor, por exemplo:

- Para valores entre 5 e 6: `=E($A$5>=5;$A$5<6)`
- Para valores entre 6 e 7: `=E($A$5>=6;$A$5<7)`
- E assim por diante...

#### Escolher cor de formatação

No campo de `Visualização` > clique em `Formatar...`

Uma janela abrirá e a aba de `Preenchimento` deve ser selecionada, nesta aba, escolha a cor de preenchimento para os valores da fórmula.

A formatação deve ficar desta maneira:

[image: Nova Regra]

Para verificar as formatações e editar, ir em `Formatação Condicional` > `Gerenciar Regras...`

Selecione `Esta Planilha` em `Mostrar regras de formatação para:`, em que a formatação deve estar desta forma:

[image: Gerenciar Regra]

### Valor de Status

Para alterar o valor da tabela, a fórmula seguinte deve ser preenchida com os valores condicionais para cara status.

`=SES(E($A$5>=4;$A$5<5);"QUESTIONÁVEL";E($A$5>=5;$A$5<6);"BOM")`

Em que para adicionar outros valores, basta inserir `E(Célula_Referência>=valor_mín;Célula_Referência<valor_máx);"STATUS"` dentro do `=SES(lógica_condicional1;"status1";lógica_condicional2;"status2";...;lógica_condicionalN;"statusN")`

### Resultado

[image: Resultado 4,5]

[image: Resultado 5,71]